# Calculating Covariance from data

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, covariance

So wikipedia says that covariance is:

$$
E[(X_i - \mu_i)(X_j - \mu_j)^T] \text{ for all i,j in the covariance matrix}
$$

Right now, I have my code set up so that I multiply (dot product) my $i$ data columns minus the average for that column by the $j$ data columns minus the average for *that* column...and I get a nice $d\times d$ matrix (where $d = \text{ data feature count (or # of columns)}$).

My question is: is that the covariance matrix? Can someone please confirm?

Or do I have to do something extra-- the $E[...]$ part of the wikipedia definition is throwing me off--does it mean that I need to do something more?

(also I got a covariance value of 116 at the $0,0$ location, with a mean of $13$ for that column vector...so I am not sure if that is correct...)

**Update**

In the comment below someone mentioned that I could estimate expectation by dividing the resulting $d \times d$ matrix by $d-1$.  Why would one do  that?

And also, numpy does not seem to implement the expectation step...does that mean it is correct to skip it on finite feature data generated from observation?

Comment: You are on the boundary between probability and statistics. The $E$ means expectation and you cannot compute that from a finite sample, only estimate it. A common estimator is to take your $d\times d$ matrix, divided by *one less* than the number of samples (data rows).

Comment: Ok, sounds like a good start...  Thanks man.